# Will the R-Squared be lower if I run the same model on a dataset with all the data vs a dataset with the quarterly averages?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, r-squared, pseudo-r-squared

Let's assume I have a dataset with quarterly data on loans. Let's say I have 100,000 of these loans, spread out in 20 quarters.

If I run a regression on all the loans, I will have 100,000 data points. If I instead take quarterly averages, the number of observations will be greatly reduced.

Would one expect to have a lower R squared in the dataset with 100,000 versus the dataset with the averages on the quarterly data?

Comment: What are the independent variables in your regression? It is difficult to answer this question without more information. For example, if there is strong variation within quarter, which you could explain when you do not take averages, you can expect the R2 to be higher in the non-averaged case. Note also that R2 reflects the explained variance relative to the total variance. When averaging, the overall variance might become lower, but this does not mean the R2 automatically increases or decreases.

Comment: The independent variables are characteristics such as Loan to Value, Years until maturity of the loan, and macroeconomic variables. So for each segment these variables will be the same per quarter, assuming we have let's say 10 segments based on the characteristics mentioned previously.